# Is it possible to create a page turning animation in Kivy

Tags: python, animation, kivy, kivymd

I am making an android app in Kivy/KivyMD for Python and was hoping to implement a page turning animation as you would have on an ereader (but for turning images if that's relevant).

At the moment I've just used a Kivy carousel to cycle through the slides but it doesn't look as smooth as I would have liked.

Is this something that would be possible in Kivy or am I looking for the sort of animation Kivy can't handle?

Thanks

Comment: maybe can try to take a look at `kivymd` ? although I think it's not that relevant lol

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually building my app in kivyMD but a Kivy carousel was the closest I could find so far